# Plot and Legend color mismatch due to opacity

Tags: plotting, legending

I have the following code:

```
ListContourPlot[data,Mesh->None,ContourStyle->None, PlotLegends->Automatic, BaseStyle->Directive[Opacity[0.3]]]
```

[image]

Due to opacity, my legend coloring is not matching my ListContourPlot.
Is there any way to fix this problem? 
I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, BaseStyle -> Opacity[.3]]` instead of `PlotLegends -> Automatic`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[1, {10, 10}]; 
ListContourPlot[data, Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> None, BaseStyle -> Opacity[0.3],
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, BaseStyle -> Opacity[.3]]]
```

[image]